# How to monitor caching in IE8

Tags: caching, internet-explorer-8, browser-cache

Im trying to check to make sure that everything on my website it being cached okay on every browser but Im struggling on finding a good tool to test IE8 caching with. Firefox has Firebug, Google Chrome has its Inspect Element toolkit IE8 has the F12 but I cant find what Im looking for in the IE8's toolkit. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to check to make sure css/html/images are being properly cached on IE8?